# Count the number matching characters between two tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How can I get a number result of 2 tables in mysql where one column is counting the number of same characters found between the 2 strings.

For example in table A I have "ABCDE"

And in table B I have: 
"ABCDE" or "CBADE" should calculate a 100%.
"ABCD" should calculate a 100% based on the length of table B.
"ABCFG "should calculate a 60%.

Comment: I don't think that MySQL is the best tool for this sort of problem.  Are you also using a programming language here?

Comment: Thanks yes, using mainly php. I'm trying to get these kpi's out with a datatable

Comment: I think a data structure well-suited here would be a set, a set of letters.  But SQL mainly likes to model _records_ as sets.  This might be doable if each letter were on a separate record in each of the two tables.